# issue with mac html signature looking funky on outlook

Tags: html, email

i have a mac html signature that looks really good when sending to other mac mail people. this is an example of how it looks properly
http://s1281.photobucket.com/user/israelrodriguez1/media/good_zpsb6ee8f6e.png.html

the problem i have is that when i send it with someone using outlook it looks really funky. this is the way it looks on outlook

http://s1281.photobucket.com/user/israelrodriguez1/media/bad_zps51e90fc2.png.html?sort=3&o=1

How can i fix this? 
the following is my mac html mail signature, the black spot is where the logo goes

```
    <div id="sig" style="min-height: 75px; line-height: 16px; margin: 6px 0; padding: 13px; border-top: 1px #999999 dotted; border-bottom: 1px #999999 dotted; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif; font-size: 10px; color: #606F78; min-width: 530px;  white-space: nowrap;" >


    <img src="http://google.com/images/some.jpg" alt="me" style="float: left; width:170px; height:81px;margin-top:-10px;padding: 2px 6px 0 0;"> &emsp;
    <!--end-->


    <strong style="color: #606F78;">FULL NAME</strong> JOB TITLE <br/>
    &emsp;
    <!-- ADDRESS -->
    Address  |  City, NY XXXXX <br/>&emsp;

    telephone | <a href="http://google.com" style="color: #606F78; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px #999999 dotted;">www.google.com</a> <br/>&emsp;


    <a href="http://google.co/" style="color: #606F78; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px #999999 dotted;">Games</a> |

    <a href="http://www.google.com" style="color: #606F78; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px #999999 dotted;">Facebook</a> | 
    <a href="http://google.com" style="color: #606F78; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px #999999 dotted;">LinkedIn</a> |
    <a href="www.google.com" style="color: #606F78; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px #999999 dotted;">Twitter</a> <br />
```

Answer (score 1):

All email clients are bad at displaying HTML. Actually Outlook use (or at least did use) Word to render HTML. Position elements with CSS (like in your case with float) is unfortunately a bad idea.

Try using a table (yeah, I know) instead with two columns.

Comment: +1. As awful as tables are for layout, they are a necessary evil when dealing with the pit of despair that is HTML email.

Comment: is it possible if you could give me an example of using a table with 2 columns in my situation. Im new to this html signature thing

Comment: I wont write it all for you, sorry. But just to get you going: http://jsfiddle.net/KRpUD/

Comment: i got it working but now the text on the right of the image is a little bit lower than the image on outlook(on a mac it shows fine). What do I use to fix it, is it padding or margin?